# How to get assembly output for a short Go program?

Tags: assembly, go

I have this program written in Go:

```
package main

func add(a, b int) int {
    return a + b
}

func main () {
    add(1,2)
}
```

For curiosity's sake, I would like to see what this program looks like in assembly.

I found a couple of ways to output assembly instructions from a Go program, mainly:

```
go tool compile -S file.go > file.S
```

Or

```
go tool objdump executable > disassembly
```

But it seems like both of these produce totally different outputs.

How can I print out human-readable assembly instructions that make up my Go program?

Answer (score 3):

Both of these give you human-readable assembly, it's just that the Go toolchain uses Plan 9 assembly syntax which is a bit weird to the untrained eye. Use a tool like `objdump` from the GNU binutils to get more familiar syntax.

Comment: To follow up, do you know of an easy way to view user code separately from the runtime packages?

Comment: See: [Go's assembly documentation](https://golang.org/doc/asm) and [an introduction to Plan 9 syntax](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/sys/doc/asm.html)

Comment: @olivia Do you mean when you are using something like `objdump`? Only dump the object files that correspond to user code, not the entire binary.

Comment: @CodyGray This is not easily done in Go as Go object files do not actually contain machine code. They use the Plan 9 approach where object files contain assembly code with some pseudo-instructions not otherwise available that is optimized during linking.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I feel like you slightly missed the question. My confusion was mainly due to the varying outputs I was getting from both commands. As I later learned it seems that when using `objdump` the resulting file contains not just the program but every library and built-in function that was compiled. At the end, I managed to use `go build -gcflags -S file.go` to print out the assembly code for my program.